# Finding records made 1 month ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a named scope to try and find records made 1 month ago, here's the code I have:

```
scope :six, -> {:conditions["records.created_at > ?", 1.month.ago]}
```

And the call:

```
@sixmonths = human.human_logins.six
```

Though I seem to be getting the following error:

```
`can't convert ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into Intege`r
```

This is occurring on the scope line.

I'm new to scopes so not sure how I should go about this, any ideas would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `:conditions` method, but the syntax, `:conditions[]` and the exception suggests that it is trying to evaluate the expression as an Array.

If you want only records created exactly 1 month ago, use the following:

```
scope :six, -> { where(created_at: 1.month.ago) }
```

If you want records created more than a month ago (which your query syntax suggests), use:

```
scope :six, -> { where('created_at < ?', 1.month.ago) }
```